# bordermatrix in MathJaX

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, math-display

It would be nice to have the option to use bordermatrix in MathJaX. See the bottom of the page http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node25.html

Comment: This doesn't seem like an SO-related feature request. This sounds like a [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) feature request.

Comment: What does SO abbreviate?

Comment: Stack Overflow.

Comment: cardinal is correct - this isn't something we can do anything about until MathJaX itself supports it.

Comment: That's generally correct, but keep in mind that it's not just about MathJax. Almost all MathJax features are modular, so even if we add it to MathJax, Stackexchange still has to decide to add it. In this case though it looks like it's just a macro, so that shouldn't be too hard. Feel free to file an issue for this feature request at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues?state=open

Answer (score 2):

There is this recent (June/13) news from mathjax.org: [Stack Exchange continues as MathJax Partner](http://www.mathjax.org/news/page/2/) posted by Peter Krautzberger.

They appreciate Cross Validated SE feedback and the following news excerpts reinforce the advices given by @cardinal and @Abby to ask for support (feature-request) directly to MathJax team:

> Stack Exchange continues its support as a MathJax Partner, demonstrating its commitment to being a partner to the math and science community on the web.
>
> MathJax continues to benefit from Stack Exchange’s help with pre-release testing and we’re grateful to get the feedback from their technical team as well as the community which keeps MathJax flexible, open and robust.
>
> We look forward to continuing the collaboration with Stack Exchange, and welcome their ongoing support for the MathJax project.

Comment: I added a comment to the OP.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, thank you for your support here.